# C++ (SFML) vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include "solarsystem.h"
#include "planet.h"
#include <vector>

static int number_of_planets, planet_type;
String planet;
String planet_id;
static std::vector<Planet> allPlanets(number_of_planets);

void Solarsystem::planets()
{
    allPlanets.size();

    srand(time(NULL));

    number_of_planets = rand() % 8 + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= number_of_planets; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        planet_type = rand() % 100 + 1;

        if (i <= 2)
        {
            if (planet_type >= 0)
            {
                planet_id = "barren";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 31)
            {
                planet_id = "gas";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 71)
            {
                planet_id = "desert";
            }
        }

        else if (i <= 5)
        {
            if (planet_type >= 0)
            {
                planet_id = "barren";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 21)
            {
                planet_id = "gas";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 41)
            {
                planet_id = "ocean";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 61)
            {
                planet_id = "continental";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 81)
            {
                planet_id = "jungle";
            }
        }

        else if (i <= 8)
        {
            if (planet_type >= 0)
            {
                planet_id = "barren";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 31)
            {
                planet_id = "gas";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 71)
            {
                planet_id = "ice";
            }
        }

        allPlanets[i] = Planet();
    }
}

void Solarsystem::render(RenderWindow &window)
{
    if (inside == true)
    {
        if (a == true)
        {
            planets();

            a = false;
        }

        planet = planet_id;

        for (int z = 1; z <= number_of_planets; z++)
        {
            int x = 700;
            int y = 100;

            if (z == 1)
            {
                allPlanets[z].planet_spr.setOrigin(700 / 2, 700 / 2);
                allPlanets[z].planet_spr.setPosition(0, 0);
            }

            else
            {
                allPlanets[z].planet_spr.setOrigin(275 / 2, 275 / 2);
                allPlanets[z].planet_spr.setPosition(x, y);

                int x = x + 700;
                int y = y + 100;
            }

            allPlanets[z].render(window, planet);
        }
    }

    else if(inside == false)
    {
        solarsystem_txt.loadFromFile("solarsystem.png");
        solarsystem_spr.setTexture(solarsystem_txt);

        window.draw(solarsystem_spr);
    }
}
```

Hello I have a problem, everytime I try to start my programm I get the Error: "Expression: vector subscript out of range"

The Error is lockated here:

```
        if (size() <= _Pos)
        {   // report error
        _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
        _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
        }
```

(not my code)

I just started using vector and I dont know what I did wrong.

Comment: You're trying to access an index that is larger than the size of your vector. Check where you're looking at `allPlanets[z]` maybe. Also, look at a stack trace for the error and follow it back to the line of your code that causes the issue. It may also be worth looking at something like `std::map` for mapping your planet string ids to integer ids.

Comment: This `for(int i = 0; i <= number_of_planets; i++)` should be `for(int i = 0; i < number_of_planets; i++)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will look up std::map

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of `number_of_planets` is 0, so the initial size of the vector `allPlanets` is also 0. The size of the vector is never changed, so all the accesses through `allPlanets[i]` are out of bounds.

Answer (score -1):

Update:

It's something wrong with "for". The code works until "std::cout << planet_type << std::endl;", the programm writes planet_type in the console one time, but not "ok" so it has to be something with "allPlanets[i] = Planet();"

```
#include "solarsystem.h"
#include "planet.h"
#include <vector>

static int number_of_planets, planet_type;
String planet;
String planet_id;
static std::vector<Planet> allPlanets;

void Solarsystem::planets()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    number_of_planets = rand() % 8 + 1;

    std::cout << number_of_planets << std::endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_planets; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        planet_type = rand() % 100 + 1;

        if (i <= 2)
        {
            if (planet_type >= 0)
            {
                planet_id = "barren";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 31)
            {
                planet_id = "gas";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 71)
            {
                planet_id = "desert";
            }
        }

        else if (i <= 5)
        {
            if (planet_type >= 0)
            {
                planet_id = "barren";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 21)
            {
                planet_id = "gas";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 41)
            {
                planet_id = "ocean";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 61)
            {
                planet_id = "continental";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 81)
            {
                planet_id = "jungle";
            }
        }

        else if (i <= 8)
        {
            if (planet_type >= 0)
            {
                planet_id = "barren";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 31)
            {
                planet_id = "gas";
            }

            if (planet_type >= 71)
            {
                planet_id = "ice";
            }
        }

        std::cout << planet_type << std::endl;

        allPlanets[i] = Planet();

        std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    }
}
```